# Give FTP User access to specific directory

Tags: apache, ftp, ssh

So I google'd around and found these instructions on how to create an FTP user and give him access to a directory

```
    To create FTP user through SSH you would need to follow below mentioned steps:

1. Login as root through SSH.

2. Next add the user account you want using the 'useradd' command

useradd <username>

3. Now create a special group for that user.

groupadd <groupname>

4. Now to add the user to the group

gpasswd -a <username> <groupname>

These commands are non-standard but
available on most popular
distributions. If not, then you can
try editing /etc/group using your
favorite text editor.

5. Change the group ownership of the special directory to that group.

chgrp -Ra groupname
/path/to/your/web/directory

6. Enable write permissions

chmod -R g+rw

/path/to/your/web/directory
```

Now that was great and all, but the problem is that on ftp, my user (named jon) logs into the directory `/home/jon` instead of the Oxford directory I set for his group, as per instructions: `/home/domain/public_html/wallpaper

If you want to change the permissions you should use the binary option rather than alphabetical. For example:

chmod 777 - for all users to do all. You would probably be better with 755 though with what you want.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What operating system is this? What FTPd are you running? This entirely depends on OS and the FTP server. On ProFTPd, for example, you can set a different user directory per user.

Comment: apache, centos, I believe I have proftpd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to change the users home directory to `/home/domain/public_html/wallpapers` by editing it in the `/etc/passwd` file.

But more information would be great. It all depends on your operating system and the ftp server.